What is the specific name of PCB coil using for LNB power supply?
I am working as an hw design engineer and create a schematic for DVB-S/S2 system. I am using a power supply IC for to supply LNB. To distinguish DVB-S signal from DC voltage, PCB coil is used . I know it is being used for hindering high frequency signal through DC power supply. You can see shape of the PCB coil below. I did not remember what is the specific name of this PCB coil?


This is above solid ground plane?

It looks like a zig zag coil.

Choke.
Or "filter inductor".
This is the term used to describe an inductor that is used as a filter, where the waveform of the current has a significant DC component that is typically greater than the AC component.  The name comes from blocking ("choking") high frequencies while passing low frequencies.
I find it strange that we don't have a similar single-word term to describe a capacitor that does the same function (not in English, anyway).  "Bypass capacitor" or "bypass cap" is the closest term that I know of.
This a good resource that explains all the different terms we use for inductors:
https://www.belfuse.com/resources/whitepaper/signaltransformer/wp-ST-Inductors-Chokes-Reactors-Filter.pdf

I wouldn't be so liberal with those terms; "choke" implies inductance over a wide range of frequencies. Presumably, the OP's example is a 1/4 wave transmission line stub, which has the same effect at resonance but only over a modest bandwidth. Whereas a "choke" proper will usually provide some octaves, decades even, of "choking" action. In any case, "decoupling" works for both L and C; together, "decoupling network". Or more specifically here, "bias tee".

Regardless, I would not refer what OP has as a "coil".  A coil, to me, implies a certain physical construction.  I think Tim Williams' 1/4 wave stub assessment is probably correct, as the trace seems to being trying to achieve a specific length, and the serpentines are too far apart to significantly affect the inductance.

@TimWilliams Thanks, interesting comments, I guess it comes down to whether we name components by their intended function when instanced, or by their form when sitting on the shelf.  Eg: when does a "resistor" become a "heater"?  Or a transistor become a switch vs an amplifier?  Same with a length of wire or a PCB trace: is it a perfect conductor, or a transmission line, "bias tee" or a power supply decoupler?  I would vote for function rather than form in most cases, since that captures more of the design intent.

The OP posted: I know it is being used for hindering high frequency signal through DC power supply. Hence, if we follow the convention of identifying a component by function rather than form, then "choke" is a perfectly good name.  The fact that this choke is implemented by a length of serpentine PCB trace does not alter the fact its function is to act as a choke in this instance.  Under a different set of circumstances, this same PCB trace could be acting as a resistance to improve current sharing in parallel switching devices, or as a heater, or as a fuse.

@SteveSh  I don't think I referred to it as a coil as such;  perhaps the OP did.   Yes, I agree that its form is not that of a coil;  but, to give the benefit of the doubt, perhaps the OP simply could not remember the term "serpentine" or "snaked" (I know that feeling); or perhaps English is not their mother tongue.   As for inductance: agreed, the serpentines are sufficiently apart that mutual coupling between trace segments (both magnetically and capacitively) is not significantly enhanced.  Cheers.
